# php how to lock a file only for read when it is writing?

Tags: php

I have a page with a larger query form mysql, the results could be more than 2MB. Because I haven't got enough memory on my server (I should arrange the memory for mysql to speed up query time), I have given up memcached. instead it is a txt file.

How to lock a file like this situation? If the file is lock, only read, if file isn't lock, first write then read. thanks.

```
if((time()-filemtime(filename)) > 60){
   //mysql_query;  query time less than 1.5 seconds
   if(ex_lock){ // if file is lock, only read
      file_get_contents($filename);
   }else{  // if file isn't lock, first write then read
      file_put_contents($filename, $query_contents);//some file size could be 2mb
      file_get_contents($filename);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [flock](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)?

Comment: @quickshiftin, I have tried flock Example #1, I have tried add `sleep(20)` in `if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {`, I find this will lock a file both read and write in the sleeping 20 seconds.

Comment: Any chance we could see a snippet of the code that does the INSERT / UPDATE of the original data into MySQL?

Comment: Another easy option to deal w/ the locking for you on the web server... SQLite ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [flock()](http://php.net/flock), but if you're creating result sets with 2MB of data I'd suggest you cache them. Does the result set really need to be updated every other second?

Comment: I have tried flock Example #1, I have tried add  `sleep` in `if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {`, I find this will lock a file both read and write.

Comment: Why would you not want to lock your write operation? If you try to write doubles, you'll just end up with broken data